# Consistency of CST implies consistency of CST plus added axiom $\mathbf U=\mathbf M$ for an inner model $\mathbf M$

Tags: set-theory

I am reading from Taras Banakh's book "Classical Set Theory: Theory of Sets and Classes". You can find it at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01613.pdf. I am now stuck on page 54 where the book is trying to prove the fact that the consistency of the Axioms of Classical Set Theory (CST) imply the consistency of (CST) plus added axiom $\mathbf U=\mathbf M$ for any inner model $\mathbf M$ (where $\mathbf U$ is the universe here). I don't understand how the book proves that if $x$ is an $\mathbf M$-definable subclass of $\mathbf M$ such that $x\in\mathbf U$, then $x\in\mathbf M$. There is a way past that to prove the Axiom of Universe, but then I can't prove the Axioms of Replacement, Union, and Power-set. Following are the details of the approach in this book.

We are working with axioms of von Neumann-Gödel-Barnays (NBG). Here (CST) are all the axioms of (NBG) excluding foundation and global choice (extensionality, universe, difference, pair, product, inversion, domain, membership, cycle, replacement, union, power-set, and infinity). An inner model is a transitive class $\mathbf M$ that contains all ordinals and is closed under Gödel's operations. Gödel's operations here are the functions $G_k:\mathbf U\times\mathbf U\to\mathbf U$ for $k\in9$ defined as follows:

- $G_0(x,y)=x$;
- $G_1(x,y)=x\backslash y$;
- $G_2(x,y)=\{x,y\}$;
- $G_3(x,y)=\mathbf E\cap(x\times y)$ (here $\mathbf E=\{(a,b)\in\mathbf U\times\mathbf U\mid a\in b\}$);
- $G_4(x,y)=x^{-1}=\{(b,a)\mid (a,b)\in x\}$;
- $G_5(x,y)=\text{dom}[X]=\{a\mid\exists b,(a,b)\in X\}$;
- $G_6(x,y)=x\times y$;
- $G_7(x,y)=\bigcup x$;
- $G_8(x,y)=x^\circlearrowright=\{(c,a,b)\mid(a,b,c)\in x\}$.

Furthermore we define the function $G:\mathbf U\to\mathbf U$ as $G(x)=\bigcup_{i\in9}G_i[x\times x]$. Then a class $X$ is called closed under Gödel's operations if for all $x\in\mathbf U$, $x\subseteq X$ implies $G(x)\subseteq X$.

Now there is a long recursive definition for what it means for a class to be $\mathbf M$-definable: Then we recursively define for all $n\in\mathbb N$ (N.B. I take $0\in\mathbb N$ even if the book doesn't, the book uses $\omega$ for $\{0,1,...\}$) a class $\text{Comp}_n\subseteq9^{2^{<n}}\times\mathbf M^{\subseteq2^n}$ ($A^B=\{f:A\to B\}$ and $2^{<n}=\{f\mid f\text{ is a function},\text{dom}[f]\in n,\text{rng}[f]\subseteq2\}$) and for each $(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_n$, we define a class $\ddot G_{\lambda,x}$ by the following recursive properties:

- If $n=0$, then $\text{Comp}_0=\emptyset$;
- If $n=1$, then $\text{Comp}_1=\{(\lambda,x)\in9^{2^{<1}}\times X^{\subseteq 2^1}\mid\lambda(0)=2\implies\text{dom}[x]=2^1\}$;
- If $n=1$, $(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_1$, and $\text{dom}[x]=2^1$, then $\ddot G_{\lambda,x}=G_{\lambda(0)}(x(\{(0,0)\}),x(\{(0,1)\}))$;
- If $n=1$, $(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_1$, and $\text{dom}[x]=\{\{(0,0)\}\}$, then $\ddot G_{\lambda,x}=G_{\lambda(0)}(x(\{(0,0)\}),\mathbf M)$;
- If $n=1$, $(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_1$, and $\text{dom}[x]=\{\{(0,1)\}\}$, then $\ddot G_{\lambda,x}=G_{\lambda(0)}(\mathbf M,x(\{(0,1)\}))$.
- If $n=1$, $(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_1$, and $\text{dom}[x]=\emptyset$, then $\ddot G_{\lambda,x}=G_{\lambda(0)}(\mathbf M,\mathbf M)$.
- If $n>1$, then
  \begin{align*}
  \text{Comp}_n=\{(\lambda,x)\in9^{2^{<n}}\times\mathbf M^{\subseteq2^n}\mid&\forall k\in2,(\lambda\circ\vec k,x\circ\vec k)\in\text{Comp}_{n-1}\,\land\\
  &\lambda(0)=2\implies\forall k\in 2,\ddot G_{\lambda\circ\vec k,x\circ\vec k}\in\mathbf U\}.
  \end{align*}
- If $n>1$ and $(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_n$, then $\ddot G_{\lambda,x}=G_{\lambda(0)}(\ddot G_{\lambda\circ\vec0,x\circ\vec0},\ddot G_{\lambda\circ\vec1,x\circ\vec1})$.

This basically encodes the ability of doing Gödel's operations a finite number of times over the elements of $\mathbf M$ and over $\mathbf M$ itself with due care to never take an unordered pair of a proper class with another class.

Then a class $X$ is $\mathbf M$-definable if there is $n\in\mathbb N$ and $(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_n$ such that $X=\ddot G_{\lambda,x}$.

Now to prove the theorem, we prove that the axioms (CST) hold when we restrict to $\mathbf M$-definable subclasses of $\mathbf M$. I am stuck at trying to prove the axioms of replacement, union, and power-set. (they state that for any set $x$ and function $F$, the classes $F[x]$, $\bigcup x$, and $\mathcal P(x)$ are sets).

In the book they use the fact that if $x$ is an $\mathbf M$-definable subclass of $\mathbf M$ such that $x\in\mathbf U$, then $x\in\mathbf M$, but it seems like the book's proof of this fact is wrong. They say that since $x\in\mathbf U$, it is legal to create the class $\{x\}$ and that this is $\mathbf M$-definable, and since $x\in\{x\}$, this implies that $x$ is a set in this model. However, for this argument to work you need to prove that $\{x\}$ is a subclass of $\mathbf M$ first, which is equivalent to $x\in\mathbf M$, so this is a circular argument.

The Axiom of Universe can be proven in another way: a set in this model is a class $x$ such that $x\subseteq\mathbf M$ and $x$ is $\mathbf M$-definable, and such that there is $X$ another $\mathbf M$-definable subclass of $\mathbf M$ with the property that $x\in X$. Then trivially $x\in\mathbf M$ since $X\subseteq\mathbf M$.

I tried to prove the above fact by induction on $n$ ($(\lambda,x)\in\text{Comp}_n$), but that didn't work because I had situations such as $X\backslash Y$ being possible sets in $\mathbf U$, but if $X$ and $Y$ are proper classes it seems to be difficult to establish that $X\backslash Y\in\mathbf M$.

I also tried to prove that every $\mathbf M$-definable class is a subclass of $\mathbf M$, but I was running into trouble when I had to take unordered pairs. If I included in the induction assumption that $\mathbf M$-definable sets are elements of $\mathbf M$, I run into the same problem with the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there was a problem with this proof. I have corrected it in [the updated version of the book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01613.pdf). In this new version the chapter "Constructibility" is totally rewritten and I hope that now everything is in order. Thank you for noticing the gap. If you will have any other questions concerning this book, please let me know.